# Initialize child models at model creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Entree which belongs to a model Vin, which itself belongs to a model Producteur.

On the form for Entree creation/edition, I want to allow the user to define the attributes for parent Vin and Producteur to create them, or retrieve them if they exist (retrieval based on user input).

For now I do the following in Entree `new`  and `edit` actions:

```
@entree = Entree.new
@entree.vin = Vin.new    
@entree.vin.producteur = Producteur.new
```

and use `fields_for` helper in the form,and that works. But I intend to have much more dependencies with more models, so I want to keep it DRY. I defined a `after_initialize` callback in Vin model which does the producteur initialization:

```
class Vin < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :vin_setup

  def vin_setup
    producteur = Producteur.new
  end
end
```

and remove the `producteur.new` from the controller. However, get an error on new action:

> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

for the line in the form that says

```
<%= fields_for @entree.vin.producteur do |producteur| %>
```

I guess that means the after_initialize callback doesn't act as I expect it. Is there something I'm missing? Also, I get the same error if I define a `after_initialize` method in the Vin model instead of definiing a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need

```
def vin_setup
  self.producteur = Producteur.new
end
```

The way you have it, you are initializing a local variable named producteur.

Comment: thanks, that does it. I thought since producteur is a defined association, it zould recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't register a call back method for `after_initialize` event. You have to implement a method called `after_initialize`.

Try this:

```
class Vin < ActiveRecord::Base
  def after_initialize
    self.producteur = Producteur.new if new_record?
  end
end
```